# Create power point using excel macro

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I have an interesting problem I am unsure of. I have not worked with power point and have little excel macro experience. I have found many similar issues to mine but none of them quite fit the bill. I am helping my local charity with a fund raiser and need a way to make a triva sort of game. The game will be displayed with powerpoint, and all the questions, choices, and answers are in an excel sheet. The way it is laid our is one question per row, and the columns are: Question, options, answers and category.

I have managed the category sorting quite easy enough, but now I need to somehow work with creating power point slides in such a way so that the question is the title, with the options being the content, and then the following slide is the answer to that question. Therefore each question creates two slides, a question and answer slide.

Example row (| denote column):

> Which of these was an italian sculptor?   |   Michelangelo, tintoretto, da vinci, galilleo    | michelangelo  |  Art

So the result would be a side with title "Which of these was an italian sculptor?" and content a) Michelangelo, b) tintoretto, c) da vinci, d) galilleo

the following slide simply being "Michelangelo"

Comment: You don't need VBA to do this. Using simple formulas in Excel to update the values of a cell referenced to your database (probably *INDEX* or *OFFSET* function and some *validation*). Then you will have to link those cells in your Power Point.

Comment: I don't have a database. Just the excel file with the columns stated above. There are 700 rows in the file and that means I need 1400 slides. How can a cell formula create a powerpoint slide?

Comment: You don't need 1400 slides. You only need 2 which updates when a selection is made in your Excel Sheet. And by *database* I mean your Excel Sheet.

Comment: I see what you are saying now. I actually do need each of the slides for the purposes of how they are displayed to the audience. Also since this is a one time thing and the people who will be running it are not computer savy, the large slide amount may be simpler. Also it is now 100 questions so 200 slides are needed now.

Comment: Try www.pptxbuilder.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to figure it out coding it myself in the excel macro. It's not the best solution, but it is easy to follow and can be modified by someone with this same issue. FYI I am the asker of this question, but my computer is in serious need of reimage and I can't log in to stack overflow...O well. Here is my code that solved this problem. Please note that all of the question were sorted by category prior so I simply changed the start and end loop control variables to make new ppts after saving and closing the previously created ones. The following code may contain code borrowed from other stack overflow questions and is repurposed:

```
Sub CreatePowerPointQuestions()

 'Add a reference to the Microsoft PowerPoint Library by:
'1. Go to Tools in the VBA menu
'2. Click on Reference
'3. Scroll down to Microsoft PowerPoint X.0 Object Library, check the box, and press Okay

'First we declare the variables we will be using
    Dim newPowerPoint As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim activeSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim Question As String
    Dim Options As String 'comma separated list of options
    Dim Choices() As String 'split up options for printing
    Dim printOptions As String 'string to print in contents of slide
    Dim Answer As String
    Dim limit As Integer
'set question amount:
    limit = 5
 'Look for existing instance
    On Error Resume Next
    Set newPowerPoint = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

'Let's create a new PowerPoint
    If newPowerPoint Is Nothing Then
        Set newPowerPoint = New PowerPoint.Application
    End If
'Make a presentation in PowerPoint
    If newPowerPoint.Presentations.Count = 0 Then
        newPowerPoint.Presentations.Add
    End If

'Show the PowerPoint
    newPowerPoint.Visible = True
'Select worksheet and cells activate
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

'Loop through each question
    For i = 1 To limit

    'Add a new slide where we will paste the Question and Options:
        newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutText
        newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
        Set activeSlide = newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)

    'Set the variables to the cells
        Question = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
        Options = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value
        Answer = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value

    'Split options into choices a,b,c,d based on comma separation
        Choices() = Split(Options, ", ")
    'Formate printOptions to paste into content
        printOptions = "A) " & Choices(0) & vbNewLine & "B) " & Choices(1) & vbNewLine & "C) " & Choices(2) & vbNewLine & "D) " & Choices(3)
        activeSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = printOptions

    'Set the title of the slide the same as the question for the options
        activeSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Question

    'Add answer slide and select it
        newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutText
        newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
        Set activeSlide = newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)
    'Set title:
        activeSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Answer:"
    'Set contents to answer:
        activeSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Answer
    'Finished with a row (question)
    Next

AppActivate ("Microsoft PowerPoint")
Set activeSlide = Nothing
Set newPowerPoint = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a commercial PPT add-in that does this *type* of thing, but unfortunately not this *exact* thing.

In outline, you'd want to start with a PPT presentation that has two slides, each of which has "placeholder" text boxes ... text boxes with text like @question@, @answer@ and so on.

The code would:

Get a count of the number of rows of data (ie, number of Q&A slide pairs needed)

Make a copy of your starting "template" PPT file, then duplicate each of the original slides n times, where n=number of rows of data in the spreadsheet.

Walk down the rows of data, for each row, replace the @question@ text in the current slide, replace the options in the current slide, increment the slide counter, replace the @answer@ in the current slide with the answer from the current row of data and so on.

You could write this either in PPT or Excel; if you're familiar with VBA/Excel, I'd do it there.